# Sql Server, Split string by 1st, 2nd and 3rd space

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Following image specifies what I am trying to achieve.. Basically I have two columns and need three extra computed columns based on these two column.

1. Split1 = 1st word after brand from product name
2. Split2 = 2 words after brand from product name
3. Split3 = 3 words after brand from product name

[image: image for what I need]

**EDIT**

e.g

**Product Name:**

Bosch Rotak 320ER Electric Rotary Lawnmower

**brand**

Bosch

Now I want three substrings out of the product name.

First - Rotak ( 1st word following the brand name)

second - Rotak 320ER ( two words following the brand name)

third - Rotak 320ER Electric ( three words following the brand name)

I hope that clarifies what I am looking for.

My current attempt looks like following. but It seems parsename works only for valid sql identifiers so I have to drop this idea.

```
select 
PARSENAME(temp.tempname, 1),
PARSENAME(temp.tempname, 2),
PARSENAME(temp.tempname, 3),
temp.tempname
from(
    select product_name, brand,
    replace(substring(product_name,CHARINDEX(brand, product_name) + LEN(brand) + 1, 10000), ' ', '.') as tempname
    from Products 
    where products.product_id = 1298665
) temp
```

Comment: I will appreciate some comments here along with downvotes so that I can improve my question if required..

Comment: Can you be sure brand is always one single word? Is finding the first blank/space a safe way to skip brand?

Comment: @jarlh No brand can be more then one word, It can appear anywhere within the product name..

Comment: So how are you going to find it?

Comment: I think this will give me starting and ending index for brand within product name..   select
CHARINDEX(table.brand, table.product_name) as startofbrand
CHARINDEX(table.brand, table.product_name) + LEN(brand) as endofbrand
from [table]

Comment: why so many downvotes..

Comment: I didn't downvote, but probably because you haven't shown us any SQL attempt.

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking. Show the test data in a proper way (not a screenshot), give some adititional test data, include your attempt you and what the expected outcome would be. That will give an idea of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Ok I appreciate the feedback. I have added some more information and my current attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I understood the question now. I am assuming the data is in a tabel so I invented another row, I used CROSS APPLY to split the rows at spaces and PIVOT to merge them again:

Test table and data:

```
DECLARE @t table(ProductName varchar(200), brand varchar(20))

INSERT @t values('Bosch Rotak 320ER Electric Rotary Lawnmower', 'Bosch')
INSERT @t values('Bosch Rotak 320ER Electric Rotary Lawnmower', 'Rotak')
```

Query:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT 
    (row_number()  over (order by (select 1))-1) / 3 id, 
    productname, 
    brand, 
    (row_number() over (order by (select 1)) -1)% 3 + 1 position,
    substring(x, 0, y.number) substr
  FROM @t
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT stuff(ProductName, 1, charindex(brand, ProductName) + len(brand), '') x
  ) x
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT top 3 number FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE 
      type = 'P' and 
      number > 0 and 
      substring(x.x, number, 1) = ' '
  ) y
)
SELECT productname, brand, [1] split1, [2] split2, [3] split3
FROM CTE
PIVOT (max(substr) FOR [position] IN ([1], [2], [3])) AS pvt
```

Result:

```
productname                   brand  split1  split2         split3
Bosch Rotak 320ER Electric..  Bosch  Rotak   Rotak 320ER    Rotak 320ER Electric
Bosch Rotak 320ER Electric..  Rotak  320ER   320ER Electric 320ER Electric Rotary
```

Comment: This has nearly worked for me. but there is one issue.. I noticed some of my products are repeating ( they becomes two rows). I am trying to understand that myself.. I removed pivot part and noticed there are three rows generated for each product row and all three rows are given same id.. But I noticed id is not same for three rows..  See here http://awesomescreenshot.com/0284e5mq44

Comment: I am sorry, I already told you a screenshot is nearly useless. I can't see if you have improvised in the script or what data is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
DECLARE @str1 VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @str2 VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @str3 VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE @some VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @some1 VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @some2 VARCHAR(max)

DECLARE @length INT
DECLARE @index INT 

--SET @index = 0
SET @some = 'Vijay Dinanath Chauhan'
SET @length = LEN(@some)

SET @index = CHARINDEX(' ',@some,0)
SET @str1 =  SUBSTRING(@some,0,@index)
SET @some1 = SUBSTRING(@some,@index,@length)
--SELECT @str1,@index AS [FirstIndex],ltrim(@some1)

SET @index = CHARINDEX(' ',@some1,@index)
SET @str2 =  SUBSTRING(@some1,0,@index)
SET @some2 = SUBSTRING(@some1,@index,@length)
--SELECT @str2,@index AS [SecondIndex],ltrim(@some2)
SET @str3 = ltrim(@some2)



SELECT @str1,@str2,@str3*/
```